# Android Auto-sync with custom data

Tags: android, android-service, android-contentprovider

Situation: I have an account for my application that I created following the example code at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html.  When clicking on the account from the Account & Sync Settings screen, I see a "Sync Contacts" checkbox.  When this checkbox is active, my custom sync successfully runs in the background.

Problem: I'm not syncing contacts, I'm syncing the application's custom data.  I would like the checkbox to say something like "Sync Historic Data"

Question: Does anyone know where I can find some documentation on how to do this, or what steps I need to take that I can search for documentation for?  Any advice or keywords to help broaden/guide my search would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a custom `android:label` attribute to the definition of your content provider in AndroidManifest.xml.

[Here](http://ericmiles.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/connecting-the-dots-with-android-syncadapter/) is a nice basic tutorial covering the basics on the SyncAdapter.

Comment: Thanks, This looks like really good summary information.  I'll give it a go this afternoon and let you know my results.

Comment: This information was extremely helpful in helping me better understand each of the components from the sample.  3 days of banging my head against the internet left me 2 permissions and one contentAuthority away from some working code.